# 2014 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3780/2014-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- During the nomination phase, (so, until January 20th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 3:00 pm EST on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this new process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 9):

> In case you already have more than 10k rep and thus access to moderator tools, why do you strive to be an elected moderator? What do you expect from being elected compared to *just being able to do what moderators do*?

Answer (score 9):

Our [answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) is currently at 78%. Do you think moderators can and should do more than average users to improve that?

If, so: how? If not: why not?

Comment: A little bit off-topic, but can you actually sort the site grid? The only reference to the `percentanswered` ID that's contained in your link is in a JavaScript object that appears to list sorting criteria with boolean values (all set to `true`). Loading the same link with [different](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) [criteria](http://stackexchange.com/sites#name) as the ID doesn't appear to change the order of the listing, nor any of the information displayed on the page.

Comment: Nevermind - ignore me. Didn't realize there was a list view. You should add `?view=list` to your link.

Answer (score 8):

How many hours a week do you plan to devote to moderation if elected? How does that compare to how many hours a week you *currently* spend active on this site? Please explain any differences in those numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 0):

What is your frustration avoidance process.

Comment: Hit the _Nuke from orbit_ button three times per day.

Answer (score 0):

What is your view about the relevance of questions about the implementation of specific plugins, such as WooCommerce?

Answer (score -7):

Please describe your experience in developing with WordPress.

Comment: Why? How is that relevant for being a good moderator?

Comment: It certainly isn't the only important thing, but wouldn't you want a moderator to have at least some expertise in the subject matter discussed?

Comment: Moderators solve communication problems. Code problems can be handled by the community.

Comment: Reading [this question](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/site-name-the-unfortunate-sequel) tells me that there are some SE moderators who are probably great moderators, but don't have a good grasp of what WordPress development is about. Both skills are important for moderating this site.

Comment: You are right, a moderator should know something about our scope. :) However, for the daily duties, patience and the ability to stay calm are more important.

Comment: I agree with @BenMiller that moderator should have both skills, but I think their reputation and questions/answers are enough to know about that.

Comment: Also, I would enjoy learning a little more about the background of the nominees. I didn't realize that it was inappropriate to ask.